# PHP/MySQL - Value Missing from recordset using inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that works fine when executed in MySQL, but when I try to use it in PHP, it's not turning the value for the joined table.

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT tbl_user.uid, tbl_user.username,
       tbl_roles.role, tbl_user.fkRole, tbl_Roles.uid
  FROM tbl_user 
 INNER JOIN tbl_roles ON tbl_user.fkRole=tbl_roles.uid 
 WHERE tbl_user.userName='AdamWest'
```

I am assigning this as $MySQLQuery to a recordset using the following:

```
include 'inc_openConStr.php';

$dbResult = mysql_query($mySQLQuery, $connStr) 
          or die ("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error() );
$numRecords = mysql_num_rows($dbResult);
$rs = "";

for($i=0;$i<$numRecords;$i++){
  $rs[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbResult); 
}
include 'inc_closeConStr.php';
```

And then I am simply trying to view it like this:

```
foreach($rs as $roleRS){

echo $roleRS['userName'].'<br/>';
echo $roleRS['role'].'<br/>';
echo $roleRS['fkRole'].'<br/>'; 

}
```

I am getting expected results for any data coming from tbl_user, but the role and uid from tbl_roles isn't showing up. I'm sure there is something obvious I am missing, but for the life of me, I cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Depending on your Server `tbl_Roles.uid` might have to be `tbl_roles.uid`.

Comment: I have tried that and I get Notice: Undefined index: tbl_users.userName in C:\xampp\htdocs\Conformance\includes\inc_getUser.php on line

Comment: Make sure your case matches that of your database and table.

Comment: var_dump(the returned row) so that you can see the actual keys. Also, it may be useful to use column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an extra array level that you don't need.  $dbResult is an array containing rows, each of which is also an array.  Your foreach loop seems to expect rows, but instead you're importing the full resultset - an array of rows - each time in the loop.  Try this:

```
$dbResult = mysql_query($mySQLQuery, $connStr) 
          or die ("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error() );
$numRecords = mysql_num_rows($dbResult);

while ($dbRow = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult) ) {

    echo $dbRow['userName'].'<br/>';
    echo $dbRow['role'].'<br/>';
    echo $dbRow['fkRole'].'<br/>'

}
```

But this data library is depreciated.  Better to switch to PDO, and then you would use foreach to interate rows through the result.